# Which encoding does Microsoft SSIS use to output flat files in Unicode?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, encoding, ssis

In the Flat File Connection Manager screen there is a checkbox to specify that the file is encoded as Unicode, but there is no way to tell which encoding will be used (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...)

Is there an official Microsoft resource as to which encoding is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unicode" in Microsoft products tends to be UTF-16LE.